# how to zoom in in and zooming out successively characters of a given a string

Tags: three.js

i am trying t crreate an html5 page with s three.js code that zooms in and zooms out successively at each character of a given string. here is my attempt:

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>Zoom In/Out Text Animation</title>
    <style>
        body {
            margin: 0;
            padding: 0;
        }
        canvas {
            display: block;
        }
    </style>
</head>
<body>
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/three.js/r128/three.min.js"></script>
    <script>
        // Set up the scene, camera and renderer
        var scene = new THREE.Scene();
        var camera = new THREE.PerspectiveCamera(75, window.innerWidth/window.innerHeight, 0.1, 1000);
        var renderer = new THREE.WebGLRenderer();
        renderer.setSize(window.innerWidth, window.innerHeight);
        document.body.appendChild(renderer.domElement);

        // Define the text and font to use
        var text = "Hello, World!";
        var fontLoader = new THREE.FontLoader();
        fontLoader.load('https://threejs.org/examples/fonts/helvetiker_regular.typeface.json', function(font) {
            // Create a geometry for each character in the text
            var textGeometry = new THREE.TextGeometry(text, {
                font: font,
                size: 50,
                height: 5,
                curveSegments: 12,
                bevelEnabled: true,
                bevelThickness: 2,
                bevelSize: 1,
                bevelSegments: 5
            });

            // Create a material and mesh for each character in the text
            var material = new THREE.MeshBasicMaterial({color: 0xffffff});
            var meshes = [];
            for (var i = 0; i < textGeometry.parameters.text.length; i++) {
                meshes[i] = new THREE.Mesh(textGeometry, material);
                meshes[i].position.x = (i * 80) - ((textGeometry.parameters.text.length-1) * 40);
                scene.add(meshes[i]);
            }

            // Define the animation function to zoom in and out each character in turn
            var animate = function () {
                requestAnimationFrame(animate);
                for (var i = 0; i < meshes.length; i++) {
                    var mesh = meshes[i];
                    var scale = Math.sin(Date.now() * 0.002 + i * Math.PI * 0.5) * 0.3 + 1.0;
                    mesh.scale.set(scale, scale, scale);
                }
                renderer.render(scene, camera);
            };

            // Start the animation
            animate();
        });

        // Set up the camera position
        camera.position.z = 200;
    </script>
</body>
</html>
```

This code uses the three.js library to create a scene with a camera and renderer, and then loads a font and creates a mesh for each character in the given text. The animation function then zooms in and out each character in turn by modifying their scale, and the renderer is used to display the scene on the page.
but it dopesn't work. i don't know why ...

Comment: Why do you use such an old version of Three.js? r128 is two years old, and the library changes fast.

Answer (score 2):

You cannot access `text` back from `TextGeometry` because it does not store it. Simple debugging would have revealed this to you. Instead, you can just use e.g. your original text variable in your loop.

Also, you are creating just one text geometry for your entire text, not one per character as you claim. Instead, try this:

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>Zoom In/Out Text Animation</title>
    <style>
        body {
            margin: 0;
            padding: 0;
        }
        canvas {
            display: block;
        }
    </style>
</head>
<body>
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/three.js/r128/three.min.js"></script>
    <script>
        // Set up the scene, camera and renderer
        var scene = new THREE.Scene();
        var camera = new THREE.PerspectiveCamera(75, window.innerWidth/window.innerHeight, 0.1, 1000);
        var renderer = new THREE.WebGLRenderer();
        renderer.setSize(window.innerWidth, window.innerHeight);
        document.body.appendChild(renderer.domElement);

        // Define the text and font to use
        var text = "Hello, World!";
        var fontLoader = new THREE.FontLoader();
        fontLoader.load('https://threejs.org/examples/fonts/helvetiker_regular.typeface.json', function(font) {


            // Create a material and mesh for each character in the text
            var material = new THREE.MeshBasicMaterial({color: 0xffffff});
            var meshes = [];

            const textGeometryParameters = {
                font: font,
                size: 50,
                height: 5,
                curveSegments: 12,
                bevelEnabled: true,
                bevelThickness: 2,
                bevelSize: 1,
                bevelSegments: 5
            };

            for (var i = 0; i < text.length; i++) {
                // Create a geometry for each character in the text
                var textGeometry = new THREE.TextGeometry(text[i], textGeometryParameters);
                meshes[i] = new THREE.Mesh(textGeometry, material);
                meshes[i].position.x = (i * 80) - ((text.length-1) * 40);
                scene.add(meshes[i]);
            }

            // Define the animation function to zoom in and out each character in turn
            var animate = function () {
                requestAnimationFrame(animate);
                for (var i = 0; i < meshes.length; i++) {
                    var mesh = meshes[i];
                    var scale = Math.sin(Date.now() * 0.002 + i * Math.PI * 0.5) * 0.3 + 1.0;
                    mesh.scale.set(scale, scale, scale);
                }
                renderer.render(scene, camera);
            };

            // Start the animation
            animate();
        });

        // Set up the camera position
        camera.position.z = 300;
    </script>
</body>
</html>
```